# Update ColB by 1 until ColA changes

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table that looks like:

```
ColA   ColB
xyz     0
xyz     0
xyz     0
uvw     0
uvw     0
stu     0
```

that I would like to be updated to:

```
ColA   ColB
xyz     1
xyz     2
xyz     3
uvw     1
uvw     2
stu     1
```

I think I need a cursor with a nested while clause, but I am a newbie to all of that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Dick

Comment: Are the updates happening only on _continuous_  `ColA` values? In other words, if another `xyz` occurs after `stu`, does its `ColB` value become `4` or start back at `1`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with a `PARTITION BY` clause.

```
SELECT
    ColA,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY ColA DESC) AS ColB
FROM MyTable
```

Note that this will label columns in arbitrary order. If you have an ID column, you can `ORDER BY` it instead.